# How to go to another html page and click a button automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got two html page A and B. When I click a link in A, I want to open B and pass a value to B. Then this value will be added into a text input in B and a button in B will be click automatically?

How to achieve this function?

Comment: Obviously by writing some code.Show us your code.Tell us where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: On page b, check value. If value exists, trigger click event. Simple.

Comment: Use `onclick` attribute as: `onclick="window.location.href='B'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´m not quite sure of what you want but i'll give it a try,
First you need JavaScript or some JS Library to achieve that and PHP.

First things First:
Create a link:

```
<a href="pageB.html">Go To Page B</a>
```

Now you can pass a value using the GET method, since you want to pass a value you will need that the page format is .PHP and not .HTML. Then you add some value to your link:

```
<a href="pageB.php?data=123">Go To Page B</a>
```

So you will have a value named "data" with '123' in it.

In page B you will need to open PHP initializer like this:

```
<?php
  $data = $_GET['data'];
?>
<input type='text' value='<?=$data?>' />
<input type='submit'id="buttonToBeClicked" >

<script>
     document.getElementById("buttonToBeClicked").click();
</script>
```

In this case you will need a form with a action. The stuff inside the  will click the button automatcly

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I didn't install php on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a form on page A, and then you will need some sort of server-side scripting language for pageB, such as PHP.  In fact, if you want to, you can use the PHP file extension for both pages. PHP includes HTML.

PAGEA.PHP  (or PAGEA.HTML)

```
<form id="myform" action="PAGEB.PHP" method="POST">
    First Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Me">
</form>
```

PAGEB.PHP

```
<?php
    $fn = $_POST['fname'];
?>

<html>
    <body>
        Received this name: <?php echo $fn; ?> <br />
        <br />
        That's right, I said [<?php echo $fn; ?>]<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript with no server side:

A.html

```
<a href="B.html#myValue">go to B</a>
```

B.html

```
<input type="text" id="my_text" />
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('my_text') = document.location.hash.substr(1);</script>
```